# grid-row changer transition/animation

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-grid

I have three elements, positioning in the middle grid-row (grid-row:2) while the element is visible (used classes .hide and .show, and js for them changing), and positioning down the middle (grid-row:3) while is hidden. I want to put a transition to that movement, the transition between the third row and the second one, and vice versa.

```
    .show{
        opacity: 1;
        grid-row: 2;
    }
    .hide{
        opacity: 0;
        grid-row: 3;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You cannot animate properties which only take integer values. So you can animate the `opacity` property, but you cannot animate the `grid-row` property.